# predict() in R stats package - At present se.fit and interval are ignored

Tags: r, predict

Is there any alternative to plotting prediction intervals for GLM models?

I've tried to create upper and lower bounds usind predict(model) but the argument 'interval' is ignored.

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried `type="response"` in your predict method? Also can you provide some code to show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to get a plot similar to what you get using stat_smooth( se=TRUE) but with prediction intervals instead of CI.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to get a plot similar to what you get using stat_smooth( se=TRUE) but with prediction intervals instead of CI. I also wanted to smooth with a power law but couldnt get `code`stat_smooth(method='nls', model='y~a*x^b',se=TRUE)`code`to plot CI, let alone fill it, so I tried to compute the Prediction interval myself. Predict.nls used to use the argument interval, it seems. I finally aproximated the power model with a glm and got SE with predict.glm (se=TRUE), calculated bounds and plotted them using geom_ribbon.Thanks again